Hardhat Ethers get Contract Deployed on a Specific Chain
I've deployed a contract(MyContract) on both ethereum sepolia and arbitrum sepolia testnets.
 async function getContractAddress() {
    const { deployer } = await getNamedAccounts();
    const myContract = await ethers.getContract(
      "MyContract",
      deployer
    );
    console.log("Getting address of Contract...");
    const contractAddress = await myContract.getAddress();
    console.log(
      `My contract is deployed at ${contractAddress}`
    );
  };

In case of above function it looks for the contract on local hardhat node and fails to find any contract.
How can I make it look for the contract on a specific network? Is there a way to get Contract address deployed on a particular chain via hardhat ethers?
I'm looking for a way to do this via code, instead of CLI.
Please help me out. Thanks is advance.

While running your script, you can pass the network flag at the end of the command, like:
npx hardhat run scripts/yourScriptFileName.js —-network desiredNetworkName

You can pass the network name like eth-sepolia, arb-sepolia, etc., depending on the exact network names that you’ve used in your hardhat.config.js file.

I'm looking for a way to do this via code, instead of CLI.

Okay. Can you add your deployment script in your question?
